# implement custom overlay on a single point google maps

Tags: google-maps, custom-overlay

I want to implement a div on a single (lat,lng) point with fixed width and height on google maps. There are examples to implement overlay within a bound and not on a single point. Has somebody implemented this ?

Comment: How big is your div? What place on that div do you want located at the "single (lat,lng) point?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an overlay on a single point by adding a custom marker to your point. Essentially, when you create the marker, you can define an icon that will replace the default Google API Marker icon:

```
    var img = 'http://placehold.it/96/ffffff'
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latLng,
        map: map,
        icon: img // replace google marker with icon
    });
```

[Link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lexxz66o/4/).

If you want an actual HTML div to overlay on Google Maps, you could convert the div into a canvas as shown in [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas)